# Buscando caractere em Posição especifica - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, pl-sql

Olá, alguém pode me ajudar? Estou construindo uma query e me deparei com alguns problemas na forma que foi estruturado o banco. Tenho uma base com vários números de telefones, e preciso que o 5° digito seja = 9. Já fiz um LEN(Telefone) = 14 para identificar somente os celulares, então simplificando preciso colocar no meu Where que traga somente onde o 5º digito seja 9

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT telefone,   
FROM 'Sua Tabela'
WHERE SUBSTRING(telefone, 5, 1) = 9;
```

Não tenho certeza se irá funcionar pois no momento não estou com meu notebook.

Comment: Muito Bom, funcionou Matheus. Muito obrigado.